# CreateJS Video Placement Issue

Tags: javascript, html, video, createjs

I'm loading and playing a streaming video using createJS. The video loads and plays just fine. But the location of the video moves around as I resize the window. Eg, the video does not remain in the same position within the windows. It shifts all over the place.

Here is a link to a video screen capture demonstrating the problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/29gwh3gui5odyvf/createjs_video_issue.mp4?dl=0

The code is really simple:

```
var videoDom = $("<div id='player'></div>").appendTo(document.body)[0];
var cjsVideo = new createjs.DOMElement(videoDom);
cjsVideo.x = 716; cjsVideo.y = 16;
stage.addChild(cjsVideo);
```

As I resize the window, I expect the video to remain in a relative fixed position.

Comment: Upon further reivew. I believe there is a simple bug in the resize calculation for createJS DomElement objects. I can demonstrate it 100% repro. The bug is: when the aspect ratio of the browser window does not exactly match the aspect ratio of the stage, the DomElement is drawn in the incorrect x,y position. This is because the calculation is using the left and top edge of the browser window, rather than the left and top edge of the stage to compute the x,y location. I don't know how to edit the createJS source, but I'm sure this is the issue. Anyone?

Comment: If possible provide a link to a demo page showing this issue in action. It'll be easier to assess that way...

Comment: Are you using CSS scaling on anything? The DOMElement assumes you can apply the same transformation matrix to the element that the stage has.

Comment: I put up a live demo here: https://pokerdev.darkcloud.com/test/videodemo.html Drag the size of the browser window to aspect ratios OTHER THAN 16:9 and you will see the problem. Drag it wider. Then taller. This is a bug in createjs.